# Syntax errror in SQL code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql code for inser test value to db:

```
INSERT INTO log (from, value) VALUES ('ABC', 'DEF')
```

I have table `log`:

```
from | value
```

`from` and `value` are `varchar(255)`.

When I run my code I a getting error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'from, value) VALUES ('ABC', 'DEF')' at line 1

I don't know why, can you give me advice? I have a syntax error in code? Or what?

Comment: `from` is  a reserved word in SQL.  It is  a really bad name for a column.  Change the name.  I'm voting to close, because `from` is an obvious reserved word.

Comment: Following the other comments you got, look carefully at your post and you may notice the reserved words have a unique blue color. If the color of "from" is different than that of "value", it should raise a suspicion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from`is a MySQL keyword. Rename the column if you can.

```
ALTER TABLE `log`
CHANGE COLUMN `from` `something_else` VARCHAR(255)
```

If you can't, use backticks around the column names.

```
INSERT INTO `log` (`from`, `value`) VALUES ('ABC', 'DEF')
```

Answer (score 1):

"from" is a reserved key word in SQL. 
Its better to change the column name.
If you don't want to change the column name then use following query. it works fine.
The Query looks like.

**insert into log(`from`,value) values ('abc','def').**
I hope that helps you!!